# How to create nested properties on a window object in one line only if they don't exist with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to create nested properties in the window object in one line if possible, and only if they don't exist.

Is there a way to simply this?

```js
window.level1        = window.level1 || {}
window.level1.level2 = window.level1.level2 || {}
```

`windows.level1` can contain data in certain conditions, so it can't be overwritten.

I tried something like the following, but it still throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'level2')`

```js
window.level1.level2 = (window.level1 || {}).level2 || {}
```

Is this possible at all in one line? If so, how?
And if there is a solution it would be great if it also works on old browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need different nesting:

```
((window.level1 = window.level1 || {}).level2 = window.level1.level2 || {}).level3 = …;
```

or using [nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) for short (and not writing the existing values into the property again):

```
((window.level1 ??= {}).level2 ??= {}).level3 = …;
```

Comment: OP asked for simplification, not shorter code. From my point of view, this is definitely complicating the code.

Comment: @connexo The main question appeared to be "*Is this possible at all in one line?*". I've added an edit with a simplification on top of that :-)

Comment: Thanks for that great answer. I thought I must apply some kind of inverse thinking, but had no starting point. This is a great example to wrap my head around.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```js
window.level1 = window.level1 ? window.level1.level2 ??= {} : { level2: {} };

console.log(window.level1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```